# Get version from Nimble Package?

Tags: nim-lang

Is there some way I can read the `version` variable from my project's `.nimble` file? Some languages include built in functions that will give you this value, does Nim have one of these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.nimble` file can be parsed with [parsecfg](https://nim-lang.org/docs/parsecfg.html). This parsing can be as complex as shown in the documentation with a `while` loop and considering all possible cases, or you can trust that the `.nimble` file follows the standard and includes a line like:

```
version = 0.1.2
```

In this case you can just search for that case like this:

```
import parsecfg

var p: Config = loadConfig("./yourPackageName.nimble")
echo p.getSectionValue("", "version")
```

The empty string passed to `getSectionValue` points to  the root of the config file, and then you extract the `version` value from there.

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the answer from @xbello, this can be evaluated statically so that the `.nimble` file doesn't need to present at run time. The key is to leverage `staticRead()` to read the file at compile time and pass it into `loadConfig()` as a stream.

```
import std/[parsecfg, streams]

const version =
    staticRead("./proj.nimble").newStringStream.loadConfig.getSectionValue("", "version")
```